# Locking selection in QTableView/QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemview, qitemselectionmodel

Is it possible to "lock" selection in QAbstractView?

I have a form with:

- A list of objects I can edit (QTableView).
  Objects are stored in a database, the list shows their ID.
- A `New` button, whose effect is to append an empty row I can edit to create a new ID and enable controls in the rest of the form.
- An `Edit` button whose effect is to enable the edition of the rest of the form, but leaves the ID non editable.
- Everything is driven by a state machine. There are parallel states but for the sake of this question, only transition between a `Viewing` state and an `Editing` state is relevant. Clicking either button enters the `Editing` state, which means testing if I am in the `Editing` state provides no information about whether I clicked on `New` or on `Edit`.

I am trying to lock the selection when entering the `Editing` state.
I cannot simply disable the view because I need to edit new IDs, I cannot connect a slot to the selectionChanged signal to restore the selection because of side effects (calls to the database + focus going all over the place), and if possible, I wish to avoid having to call `QAbstractItemView::setSelectionModel` (it is reset by `QAbstractItemView::setModel`, see below) and wish to drive this behavior thanks only to the `Viewing` and `Editing` states.

I have tried to use, but to no avail:

- `QAbstractItemModel::flags` (the best I can do is prevent selecting another item but not clearing the selection.)
- `QAbstractItemView::selectionMode`
- `QItemSelectionModel::select`, with `QItemSelectionModel::SelectionFlag::NoUpdate` (The description of this enum value made me think it could block the next selection change but that is not the case).
- Subclassing `QItemSelectionModel` (@chehrlic's comment below) to override all the `virtual` public slots.
  While it does work (a property can be used to stop the selection from changing), it is a pain that `QAbstractItemView::setModel` creates a new model. It does work now but I do not see any easy way to prevent the code from breaking after accumulating code changes over the span of several years.

Did I miss any existing property to achieve this? And if I did not, how can I implement a property to lock the selection but no have any other effect on my view?

At this point, the last item in the above list of things I tried does do the job but it has a downside I am trying to avoid.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078003/locking-selection-in-qt-graphics-view) except it was for a now old version of Qt and the answer is not very satisfying anyway.

Comment: Did not tried it out but create a custom selection model derived from [QItemSelectionModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qitemselectionmodel.html) and override the select() functions so they don't do anything when you're in edit mode.

Comment: @chehrlic Well, yes subclassing `QItemSelection` model does the trick, that is the best among the options I have so far; I would not qualify that as an ideal solution though: `QAbstractItemView::setModel` creates a new selection model, which means the code could break down by just moving the `view->setModel(...)` for any reason in a few years time. Had `QItemSelectionModel` come with a clone method, the views could create a selection model of the right type; that is not the case though.

Comment: I will edit the question and answer my own question if I find a better way some day, unless someone else has a solution first; wait and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time and no answer from the community, the best solution I can come up with is:

1. Subclassing QItemSelectionModel to:

   - Create a private attribute `bool selectionLocked;` that drives when changes of selection must be disallowed.
   - Override all the `virtual` public slots so that, when `selectionLocked == true`, they immediately return.
2. Using a `QIdentityProxyModel` as was explained in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77507362/20143744) (in the section discussing QTBUG-49966) to cope with selection models being created every time `setModel(...)` is called on the view.
   If for any reason, I need to change the model attached to a view, I can do it calling `QAbstractProxyModel::setSourceModel` instead of `QAbstractItemView::setModel`, thus ensure the selection model never gets inadvertently reset.

This is not the full future-proof solution I was envisioning (this does not protect the application against someone adding a call to `setModel` in the future) but it will do for me.