# Shared selection for several QTableWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget

I'm working in Qt 5.6.1. **There are several QTableWidget tables**, in theory they represent one table - they are located closely, and the data on the rows is interconnected, but they should be presented as separate widgets. Their selection flag is SelectRows, and the ExtendedSelection mod. **How can I make a general selection for them?** Let's say you selected several rows of the first table and selected the same rows in others. The selection should be removed accordingly. Tables have different numbers of columns.

I tried to handle the `selectionChanged` signal from the selectionModel tables in this way:

```
void wSpisokActive::selectionChangedMain(const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)
{
    permission_to_changed_main_ = false; // flag to exit a similar slot in another table

    if (permission_to_changed_monitoring_) { // select row
        QModelIndexList selected_list = selected.indexes();
        for (QModelIndex model_index: selected_list) {
            ui->tbMonitoring->selectRow(model_index.row());
        }

        QModelIndexList deselected_list = deselected.indexes();
        int last_row = -1;
        for (QModelIndex model_index: deselected_list) { // deselect row
            if (last_row == model_index.row()) continue;
            last_row = model_index.row();
            for (int i = 0; i < ui->tbMonitoring->columnCount(); ++i) {
                ui->tbMonitoring->selectionModel()->select(ui->tbMonitoring->model()->index(last_row, i), QItemSelectionModel::Deselect);
            }
        }
    }

    permission_to_changed_main_ = true;
}
```

But this way selection via Ctrl is processed incorrectly. Also, when selecting several rows, only the last one is highlighted - I tried setting `ui->tbMonitoring->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);` before selecting rows, and after `ui->tbMonitoring->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);`. But it didn't help.

Comment: If the selection behavior is `SelectRows` and the row count is consistent, there's an alternative: instead of having multiple QTableWidgets, just use *one* and use QTableView for the others. The first one will have the full table contents, and the others will use its model; then you can call `setColumnHidden()` for each table based on those you want displayed on the others. Finally, set the selection model of the first table to all the others.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your reply! This is an interesting solution, I'll try it on Monday. Then i can make all the tables like QTableView, and have a pointer to the QTableWidget somewhere in the code. Then i will get a selection when i click on a row in one table in all the others?

Comment: Do you mean, use a "hidden" QTableWidget? At that point, it makes little sense to have a QTableWidget: just create a single QStandardItemModel common for all views, and share the same item selection model between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this help page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-in-item-views) (my emphasis):

> Information about the items selected in a view is stored in an instance of the QItemSelectionModel class. This maintains model indexes for items in a single model, and is independent of any views. Since there can be many views onto a model, **it is possible to share selections between views**, allowing applications to show multiple views in a consistent way.

The methods you are interested in come in pairs:

- [`model`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#model) / [`setModel(QAbstractItemModel*)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#setModel)
- [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) / [`setSelectionModel(QItemSelectionModel*)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#setSelectionModel)
  For that last one, spare a minute to carefully read what the documentation says, that is:

  > Note that, if you call setModel() after this function, the given selectionModel will be replaced by one created by the view.

  > It is up to the application to delete the old selection model if it is no longer needed [...]

The resulting code looks like (assuming this is on your main thread):

```cpp
auto widgetModel    = myTableWidget->model();
auto widgetSelModel = myTableWidget->selectionModel();
for (auto view : { myTableView1, myTableView2, myTableView3 }) {
    view->setModel(widgetModel);
    delete view->selectionModel();
    view->setSelectionModel(widgetSelModel);
}
```

---

**Edit:** About [QTBUG-49966](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49966), pointed out by @musicamante in comments.

To cut the chase: **YES**, 1 selection model per view (rather, 1 selection model for the header view of the view) will remain in memory until the view is deleted, along with its header.
However, if you do nothing more than what I presented above, you will only have 1 selection model "leaked" per view (which should be a very small number) which get deleted when you delete the view.

If you are implementing a window where `setModel` gets called any number of time (e.g. see the scenario described by @musicamante in comments), there are several things you can do as a mitigation measure:

1. To limit the lifetime of the memory leak:

   - AFAICT, all the selection models created by Qt have a parent set.
     If you make sure widgets are deleted (the easiest way to ensure everything gets cleared when you close a window is by calling `myWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);`), these unused selection models will not outlive your views.

   > *If you never delete the views/widgets, then the memory leak is on you (**you** never delete the objects you create) rather than because of the unused selection models created by Qt.*

   - Never create a selection model by yourself, at least without setting its parent. I hope it is obvious but never call `mySelectionModel->setParent(nullptr);` either.
     As long as all selection models have a view as their parent, they will get deleted with the view.
2. To limit the size of the memory leak:
   You must make sure not to call `setModel()` more than once per view:

   - If your model supports being [reset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel), then use this possibility.
     Example with [`QSqlTableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html): changing the SQL table loaded should **not** be done by creating a new model to substitute it to the existing one. Instead, do:

   ```cpp
   myExistingSqlTableModel->setTable(newlySelectedTable);
   myExistingSqlTableModel->select();
   ```

   - In the event where you do have to change the model (e.g. because the model does not support being reset or because the new model is not of the same type as the existing one), you still have a way out thanks to [`QIdentityProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qidentityproxymodel.html).
     The purpose of a proxy model is not supposed to be this but it comes in handy here. The model can be changed on a view (at least, this is what it visually looks like) without calling `setModel`.
     It is intialized by doing:

   ```cpp
   QIdentityProxyModel* proxyModel = new QIdentityProxyModel(myView);
   proxyModel->setSourceModel(myModel);
   myView->setModel(proxyModel);
   ```

   Then, attaching a new model to your view can be done:

   ```cpp
   if (auto proxyModel = dynamic_cast<QAbstractProxyModel*>(myView->model()); proxyModel) {
       if (proxyModel->sourceModel())
           delete proxyModel->sourceModel();
       proxyModel->setSourceModel(myNewModel);
   }
   ```

   And voilà! no more calling `setModel` several time on the same view.

---

On a related note, if I can make a quick (optional) recommendation:

- Experienced Qt developers tend to favor `QListView`, `QTableView`, `QTreeView` over their `QxxxxxWidget` counterparts.
  While `QTableWidget` is a class of choice for beginners, simplifying a lot of the required work, it sets such limitations on flexibility that the downsides far outweigh the advantages.
- Experienced Qt developers also tend to avoid `QStandardItemModel` (note `QxxxxxWidget` classes all use their own internal standalone model) if they can.
  If your application already has some internal structure to store the data shown on screen, it is usually more efficient to **map** it to a custom subclass of `QAbstractItemModel` rather than **copy** it into a standalone model such as `QStandardItemModel`.

The sooner you get used to creating your own model classes, the easier your life will become down the line.
In your case, you are working with tables, you can start your learning journey with [`QAbstractTableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstracttablemodel.html). It should be accessible enough as a starting point and generally speaking easier to subclass compared to `QAbstractItemModel`.

*The above will work with your current code so feel free to ignore this advice*.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I just realized that `setModel()` results in a memory leak for the headers' selection model (see [QTBUG-49966](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49966), because it directly calls `setModel()` on them (which, in turn, create their own selection model), but then it overwrites it by explicitly calling `setSelectionModel()` with that of the table. So, at least in your example, the resulting "ghost" selection models of the headers should be destroyed along with that of the view.

Comment: @musicamante: TBH, I have not understood the comments by Christian Ehrlicher (1 Feb 2018). When I read the code, everything ends up calling `QAbstractItemView::setModel`, in which the selection model is created by this line: `QItemSelectionModel *selection_model = new QItemSelectionModel(d->model, this);`. So the view (including header view) is set as the parent of the selection model, and it should be deleted with it (including the case of calling `setModel(nullptr);`).

Comment: So as long as you never call `new QItemSelectionModel()` yourself (which the above code avoids doing, it reuses a selection model that was previously created inside `setModel()`) and without a parent, and you ensure your widgets get deleted (if you don't, then you would have a leak but on the widgets themselves), the memory should eventually be freed, should it not? And if this is true, the "leak" only becomes problematic if you repeatedy change the model on a long-lived view but I cannot picture a scenario where that would happen... Anything wrong in my analysis?

Comment: As long as I can understand the code (sorry, I'm a Python user, so I only have a partial understanding of C++), when `QTableView.setModel()` (and, similarly, QTreeView) is called, it also calls `setModel()` on its headers. This results in the creation of further QItemSelectionModel on the headers: it's not controllable, but it's also the expected behavior of any QAbstractItemView. But, *then*, QTableView *also* creates its own selection model as expected, and sets it on its headers for consistency, *without* checking about the previously created selection model they just created.

Comment: I know that it's a peculiar scenario, but it's not that rare: for example, you may have a persistent view that switches models based on an external aspect; imagine a QListView that lists a few models in its items (for instance, representing different tables in a database), and a QTableView that shows their contents when an item (model) of the list is selected. I understand the default behavior and the implications of doing such a change, but this aspect should at least be explained in the docs for model views that use QHeaderViews.

Comment: I see, let me edit with some insights...

Comment: Thank you both! I'll accept this as an answer.